# Can't deploy Ionic app with Firebase No matching client found for package name

Tags: android, firebase, ionic-framework, ionic3

I created ionic 3 app with firebase

the application start correctly, and connected to firebase DB.and can perform CRUD operations.

when I deploy app using command

```
$ ionic cordova build --release android
```

I got error message:

```
No matching client found for package name 'io.ionic.starter'
```

note: the file 'google-services.json' is missing
and my app is not shown inside Firebase console [pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7e88B.png)

I initialize firebase inside app module:

```
// Initialize Firebase
var config = {
  apiKey: "AIzaSyDGJaayYxyasdufYG7GKo36nUMdsfU",
  authDomain: "firedo-3997a.firebaseapp.com",
  databaseURL: "https://firedo-3997a.firebaseio.com",
  projectId: "firedo-3997a",
  storageBucket: "firedo-3997a.appspot.com",
  messagingSenderId: "578088897558"
};
firebase.initializeApp(config);
```

please help me deploying this app

Comment: Did you added google-service.json file ???

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a google-services.json file to the root file of your ionic project from firebase.
And you must make the  in the config.xml file like the name of your project in firebase.